# Binding parameters is not supported for the statement Java

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

hello I am sending a query with this data to my postgres database but I am getting this error and I have not been able to solve it

my query

```
public interface MyReactiveRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<MyEntity, String> {
 @Modifying
@Query("update CCPSEDCD.RECFFTAPSE set id=1, tarmoda='c' where id=1")
}
```

error
"Binding parameters is not supported for the statement 'update CCPSEDCD.RECFFTAPSE set id=1, tarmoda='c' where id=1'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try change:

```
@Query("update CCPSEDCD.RECFFTAPSE set id=1, tarmoda='c' where id=1")
```

for:

```
@Query("update MyEntity m set m.id = 1, m.tarmoda = 'c' where m.id = 1")
```